# Getting error org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a review class which has many employees.

The association in Review.java is

```
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "review_employee", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "reviewid") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "empid") })
    private Set<Employee> employees;
```

When I try to access the employees from Review I am getting the following error

```
   org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [review0_.id.employees] with element property reference [id] [FROM com.abc.model.Review r  LEFT JOIN fetch r.employees WHERE r.id = 1 AND ( r.employees.id = 11 )]
   org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
```

Thanks for your help.

---

### Update

> Employee.java

```
public class Employee  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "empfirstname", nullable = false)
private String empFirstName;

@Column(name = "emplastname", nullable = false)
private String empLastName;

@Column(name = "empdesignation", nullable = false)
private String empDesignation;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employeetypeid", nullable = true)
private EmployeeType employeeType;

@Column(name = "employeeImageFileName", nullable = false)
private String employeeImageFileName;

private Boolean deleted;

...Getters & Setters...
}
```

---

> Review.java

```
public class Review {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "review_employee", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "reviewid") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "empid") })
private Set<Employee> employees;

@Column(name = "customerfirstname", nullable = false)
private String customerFirstName; 

@Column(name = "customerlastname", nullable = false)
private String customerLastName;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "starratingid", nullable = false)
private StarRating starRating;

@Column(name = "reviewtitle", nullable = false)
private String reviewTitle;

@Column(name = "review", nullable = false)
@Type(type="text")
private String review;

 ...Getters & Setters...
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the structure of Employee entity?

Comment: @KarthikR added the structure of Employee entity

Comment: Thanks. Employee is fine. Can you please add the Review class' entity? I doubt it with the id of Review class. Is it a composite key?

Comment: WHere is your query?

Comment: @KarthikR Added Review,java

Comment: @SubodhJoshi You can see the query within the error itself. I am retrieving all reviews which fulfil following condition: "FROM com.abc.model.Review r  LEFT JOIN fetch r.employees WHERE r.id = 1 AND ( r.employees.id = 11 )"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the reference of the employee from the JOIN'ed employee and not the Reviews' employee. Try this :

```
FROM com.abc.model.Review r LEFT JOIN fetch r.employees reviewEmp WHERE r.id = 1 AND reviewEmp.id = 11
```

Comment: :) It's good to remember that "illegal attempt to dereference collection" is mostly related to accessing of collection where the collection is directly referenced instead of being called via the JOIN'ed class' reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your below query

```
 FROM com.abc.model.Review r LEFT JOIN fetch r.employees WHERE r.id = 1 AND ( r.employees.id = 11 )
```

should be modified like this

```
FROM com.abc.model.Review r LEFT JOIN fetch r.employees emp WHERE r.id = 1 AND ( emp.id = 11 )
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Tried it out but still the error is there.

Comment: Which Hibernate version you are using ?

Comment: If I try this I am getting this error:   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: employees of: com.abc.model.Employee [FROM com.abc.model.Review r  LEFT JOIN fetch r.employees emp WHERE r.reviewStatus.id = 1 AND ( emp.employees.id = 11 )]

Comment: Actually he has a typo in it. ( emp.employees.id = 11 ) should be replaced with ( emp.id = 11 ). That's my answer as well. Please try.

Comment: Are you joing with `SET` or the `emp` class object ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I tried your earlier answer (before editing) and it seems like you had a typo. But as you have edited your answer, its the same solution which worked and which was also shared by Karthik. Thanks for your help.